# Send message or chrome.runtime.getBackgroundPage()

Tags: google-chrome-extension

In order to access information from my `background.js` file (my background script), I realized I have two options: I can send a message from my background script to my other script, or I can run `chrome.runtime.getBackgroundPage()`. Both options work well, but does anyone know if one is faster or more efficient than the other?

Comment: See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54715122), it describes some of the differences. Generally messaging is a better choice because with getBackgroundPage one may have to do a deepClone manually in order to avoid memory leaks when copying objects/arrays and any other non-primitive type. But it should be noted that when performance is concerned you need to measure it, never guess.

Answer (score 0):

I think coding with getBackgroundPage() is much easier and more clearly.

When using messaging you have to deal with asynchronicity, listeners, sendResponse and various other things making the code more confusing than necessary.

Doing it with getBackgroundPage is easy:

popup.js:

```
 bg = chrome.runtime.getBackgroundPage();
 response = bg.doSomething(param);
 console.log(response);
```

background.js:

```
function doSomething(param) {
    // functionality
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Decided to go with that option. Thanks for the feedback!