# Chrome Extension: Cannot access contents of URL starting with "chrome-extension://"

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

In my extension, I am creating a tab and opening a html file named `results.html` in it from my background script named `background.js` . After creating a tab I am injecting a javascript file named `results.js` to that newly created tab.

But it throws the following error in my `background.js` console:

```
Unchecked runtime.lastError: Cannot access contents of url "chrome-extension://hcffonddipongohnggcbmlmfkeaepfcm/results.html". 
Extension manifest must request permission to access this host.
```

Going through the solutions on other stackoverflow questions I have tried adding following permissions in `manifest.json`:

1. `<all_urls>`
2. `chrome-extension://*` Error thrown: Permission 'chrome-extension://*' is unknown or URL pattern is malformed.

But none of above worked.

Also the `results.js` after injected is supposed to send message to `background.js` to get in response some data to feed in `results.html` .

My Code:

manifest.json

```
{
  "manifest_version":2,
  "name":"Extension Name",
  "description":"This is description of extension.",
  "version":"1.0.0",
  "icons":{"128":"icon_128.png"},
  "browser_action":{
      "default_icon":"icon.png",
      "default_popup":"popup.html"
  },
  "permissions":["activeTab", "background", "tabs", "http://*/*", "https://*/*","<all_urls>"],
  "background": {
      "scripts": ["background.js"],
      "persistent": false
  },
  "web_accessible_resources": ["addAlias.js","results.html","results.js"]
}
```

background.js

```
/*Some code*/
function loadResult()
{
  chrome.tabs.query({active:true},function(tabs){
    //creating tab and loading results.html in it
    chrome.tabs.create({url : 'results.html'}, function(tab){
      //injecting results.js file in the tab
      chrome.tabs.executeScript(tab.id, {file: 'results.js'});  
    });
  });
}
/*somecode*/
if(/*some condtion*/)
{
    loadResult(); //calling function 
}


chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(request,sender,sendResponse)
{
  //Listening for results.js request for data
  if( request.greeting === "sendResults")
    {
      console.log(" Results request received .");
      //sending data back to results.js
      sendResponse({failed:failedToAdd,succeed:succeedToAdd});

    }
}
```

results.js

```
/*Some code*/
console.log("I got loaded");
console.log("Now requesting for sendResults");

//Below sending request for data
chrome.runtime.sendMessage({greeting: "sendResults"},
      function (response) {
        console.log('Got data from Background.js');
        /*Some Code*/
      }
  );
```

Comment: executeScript exists only to run content scripts in web pages, you can't use it here. See [Pass data or modify extension html in a new tab/window](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54715122)

Comment: @wOxxOm thanks taking inspiration from 4th method I added results.js to results.html and initiated message from results.js

Comment: @wOxxOm can you please write down an answer here so that I could accept it as a solution.

Comment: It may make more sense if you post fragments from your working solution.

Comment: did you figure out how to inject there?

Answer (score 2):

You need to add the host_permissions in the manifest.json.
An example of adding host permission in manifest.json
`"host_permissions":["*://ahainstructornetwork.americanheart.org/"]`

Check this article for details: https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv3/declare_permissions/#host-permissions

Comment: Only works with manifest v3 not applicable in v2 as OP has

Comment: It doesn't work in MV3 either. If you add `"<all_urls>"` to `host_permissions`, the error persists. If you add `"chrome-extension://*/*"` or `"chrome-extension://*"`, you get a different error, complaining that `chrome-extension` is not a valid scheme.

Comment: the link does not show `host_permissions` configuration key.

Answer (score 1):

Put this in your manifest.json:

```
"host_permissions": ["*://*/*"],
```