# Chrome Extension: chrome.tabs.create fails to create the URL content when the body content is large

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

Below code works fine (new is tab created and content displayed) when the request.log size is around 1MB. When the request.log is large i.e greater than ~1MB, it fails to create/display URL with the content (A new tab is launched with no content displayed and browser bar is empty. There are no errors printed in background page).

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(request, sender) {
  var htmlCode = "<html><body><pre>" + request.log + "</pre></body></html>";
  var url = "data:text/html," + encodeURIComponent(htmlCode);

chrome.tabs.create({url: url}, (tab) => {
      setTimeout(() => {
     }, 3000);
   })
});
```

Comment: Chrome has a 2MB limit on the URL length which corresponds to 1M characters. Use a different approach: [Pass data or modify extension html in a new tab/window](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54715122)

Comment: Thanks. Any suggestions on alternative option for injecting the body content into the new tab?

Comment: Yes, see the link in my comment above.

Comment: Thanks for sharing this. I will try it out.