# How to show an alert from a Chrome Extension but centered in the main browser window

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I have a Chrome Extension that needs to display an alert.

If I call `alert(....)` inside the `popup.js` script, it is shown over the `popup.html` page. The same happens if I use a third party library, such as `alertify`.

In my case, my `popup.html` page is very small, so it looks ugly when the alert is displayed.

Is there a way to show it in the browser Window?

Just in case, this is the manifest.json:

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "MyExtension",
  "description": "",
  "version": "1.1",
  "permissions": [

  ],
  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "img/icon16.png",
    "default_popup": "popup.html"
  },
  "externally_connectable": {
    "matches": [ "*://localhost:*/*" ]
  },
  "icons": {
    "16": "img/icon16.png",
    "32": "img/icon32.png",
    "48": "img/icon48.png",
    "128": "img/icon128.png"
  },
  "web_accessible_resources": [ "img/logo.jpg" ]
}
```

Jaime

Comment: Use chrome.windows.create with a html page and `type: 'popup'`, see also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54715122).

Comment: That could work, however, popup is not opened as modal. That is, a user could click outside and the popup will be hidden.

Comment: The thing I suggest is not related to the main popup, see the description of chrome.windows.create.

Comment: You might be able to inject a content script into the current tab to trigger the alert. Generally, you have almost no control over how `alert()` presents the popup.

Comment: Finally I have opened a new Google tab from the extension. That way I can place any message I need to show to the user.