# Creating own chrome extension: How to fetch bookmarks favicons and open local html file

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, favicon, bookmarks, local-files

This is my first Chrome extension that I am creating. I needed a simplified and much faster version of the bookmarks sidepanel. I've managed to list my chrome bookmarks and FINALLY do some really deep search to understand how to open a local URL "file://" I had to create a content.js file, so that's part of a solutions, but it's not the complete one.

I still have not found out how to load the favicon that chrome stores in it's cache. I would really love someone to help me on this.

I encountered a new problem when solving the previous one, my div is NOT always created on everypage AND even sometimes dissapears or becomes empty for some reason, noteable the LOCAL files AGAIN but my content.js scripts run. I have no clue as to why this is happenning.

Here is my source code for each file:

**manifest.json:**

```
    {
        "name": "Favorites Sidebar",
        "version": "0.0.0.1",
        "manifest_version": 2,
        "description": "Displays a sidebar with the list of your favorites.",
        "icons": {
            "16": "icons/favorites16.png",
            "32": "icons/favorites32.png",
            "48": "icons/favorites48.png",
            "128": "icons/favorites128.png"
        },
        "background": {
            "scripts": ["background.js"],
            "persistent": false
        },
        "content_scripts": [
            {
                "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
                "css": ["style.css"],
                "js": ["content.js"]
            }
        ],
        "permissions": [
            "activeTab",
            "*://*/*",
            "bookmarks"
        ]
    }
```

**background.js:**

```
    var scode = "";
    var fav_list = "";
    var sfullbody = "";

    var sicondir = "<div style=\\\"padding: 0; margin: 1px 4px 1px 4px; display: inline-block;\\\">";
    sicondir += "<div style=\\\"position: relative; width: 8px; height: 2px; border-radius: 3px 3px 0 0; background-color: #C19536; padding: 0; margin: 0;\\\"></div>";
    sicondir += "<div style=\\\"position: relative; width: 16px; height: 10px; border-radius: 0 3px 3px 3px; background-color: #C19536; padding: 0; margin: 0;\\\"></div>";
    sicondir += "</div>";

    var jvshowdir = "var odir = document.getElementById(\\'%dirname%\\');";
    jvshowdir += "var sdisp = odir.style.display;";
    jvshowdir += "if (sdisp == \\'block\\') {";
    jvshowdir += "odir.style.display = \\'none\\';} else {";
    jvshowdir += "odir.style.display = \\'block\\';}";

    var ilogcnt = 0;
    var curtid = 0;
    var cururl = "";

    chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(message, sender, sendResponse){
        console.log("message.url:"+message.url);
        console.log("sender:"+sender.id);
        chrome.tabs.getSelected(null,function (tab) {
            curtid = tab.id;
        });
        console.log(curtid);
        chrome.tabs.update(message);
    });

    chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(
        function(tabId, changeInfo, tab) {

            chrome.bookmarks.getTree(GetFavs);
            
            scode += "var pdiv = document.getElementById('daric-fav-overlay');";
            scode += "var odiv = -1;";
            scode += "if (!pdiv) {";
            scode += "var odiv = document.createElement('div');";
            scode += "} else {";
            scode += "odiv = pdiv;";
            scode += "odiv.innerHTML = '';";
            scode += "}";
            scode += "odiv.id = 'daric-fav-overlay';";
            scode += "odiv.innerHTML = \""+fav_list+"\";";
            scode += "document.body.insertAdjacentElement('afterbegin',odiv);";
            
            chrome.tabs.executeScript(
                null,
                {code: scode}
            )
            
        }
    );

    function GetFavs(treeItem,subDir="",FirstItem = true) {
        var ictr = 0;
        var ofav = -1;
        var sitem = "";
        var stitle = "";
        var stmp = "";
        var surl = "";
        var itlen = 0;
        var iclen = 0;
        var sjvdc = "";
        var sdash = "";
        var item1 = FirstItem;
        
        itlen = treeItem.length;
        
        // Loop all favorites
        for (ictr = 0; ictr < itlen; ictr ++) {
            ofav = treeItem[ictr];
            iclen = 0;
            if (ofav.children) {iclen = ofav.children.length;}
            
            // Get favorite's title if any
            if (ofav.title != "") {
                stitle = ofav.title;
                stitle = stitle.replace(/\'/g,"\\'");
                stitle = stitle.replace(/\"/g,"\\\"");
            }
            
            // Get children list
            if (iclen > 0 || typeof ofav.url === "undefined") {
                // Show favorite's title
                if (ofav.title != "") {
                    // Replace spaces by dash
                    stmp = stitle;
                    stmp = stmp.replace(/ /g,"-");
                    // Build directory clickable menu
                    sjvdc = jvshowdir;
                    sjvdc = sjvdc.replace(/%dirname%/g,stmp);
                    // Do not set the root folder as a clickable folder
                    sitem = "<div style=\\\"font-weight: bold; font-style: italic;margin: 4px 0 0 4px; padding: 0;\\\">"+stitle+"</div><div class=\\\"root-list\\\">";
                    if (item1 == false) {
                        sitem = "<div class=\\\"daric-folder\\\" id=\\\"dir-"+stmp+"\\\" onclick=\\\""+sjvdc+"\\\">";
                        sitem += sicondir+stitle+"</div><div class=\\\"daric-sub-folder\\\" style=\\\"display: none;\\\" id=\\\""+stmp+"\\\">";
                    }
                    // Make sure to only add different folders
                    if (!fav_list.includes(sitem)) {fav_list += sitem;}
                    item1 = false;
                }
                // Get children list
                if (subDir != "") {sdash = "--";}
                GetFavs(ofav.children,subDir+sdash+stmp,item1);
                fav_list += "</div>";
            } else {
                // No children found, this is probably a bookmark link
                surl = ofav.url;
                // Create a valid ID from title
                sdash = subDir+"-"+Dashify(stitle);
                // Check if item already exists;
                if (!fav_list.includes(sdash)) {
                    //if (fav_list.includes(sdash)) {sdash += "-"+Math.floor(Math.random()*100000).toString();}
                    sitem = "<div class=\\\"daric-fav\\\" id=\\\""+sdash+"\\\">&nbsp;&nbsp;"+stitle+"</div>";
                    sitem += "<input id=\\\"daric-url-"+sdash+"\\\" class=\\\"daric-hidden\\\" type=\\\"text\\\" value=\\\""+surl+"\\\"/>";
                    fav_list += sitem;
                }
            }
            
        }
    }

    // Replace numourous possible troublesome characters to dashes "-"
    // Good for class or id names
    function Dashify (sString) {
        var sdash = sString;
        
        sdash = sdash.replace(/ /g,"-");
        sdash = sdash.replace(/\"/g,"-");
        sdash = sdash.replace(/\'/g,"-");
        sdash = sdash.replace(/\:/g,"-");
        sdash = sdash.replace(/\(/g,"-");
        sdash = sdash.replace(/\)/g,"-");
        sdash = sdash.replace(/\[/g,"-");
        sdash = sdash.replace(/\]/g,"-");
        sdash = sdash.replace(/\{/g,"-");
        sdash = sdash.replace(/\}/g,"-");
        sdash = sdash.replace(/\./g,"-");
        sdash = sdash.replace(/\,/g,"-");
        sdash = sdash.replace(/\;/g,"-");
        sdash = sdash.replace(/\</g,"-");
        sdash = sdash.replace(/\>/g,"-");
        sdash = sdash.replace(/\?/g,"-");
        sdash = sdash.replace(/\!/g,"-");
        sdash = sdash.replace(/\%/g,"-");
        sdash = sdash.replace(/\^/g,"-");
        sdash = sdash.replace(/\$/g,"-");
        sdash = sdash.replace(/\#/g,"-");
        sdash = sdash.replace(/\@/g,"-");
        sdash = sdash.replace(/\*/g,"-");
        sdash = sdash.replace(/\&/g,"-");
        sdash = sdash.replace(/\~/g,"-");
        
        return sdash;
    }
```

**content.js:**

```
    var sid_down = "";
    var sid_up = "";

    document.addEventListener("mousedown",function(e){
        sid_down = "daric-url-"+e.target.id;
    },false);

    document.addEventListener("mouseup",function(e){
        sid_up = "daric-url-"+e.target.id;
        // send message ONLY if we mouseup on the same element
        if (sid_up == sid_down && typeof document.getElementById(sid_up) !== "undefined") {
            chrome.runtime.sendMessage({url: document.getElementById(sid_up).value});
        }
    },false);
```

**style.css:**

```
    #daric-fav-overlay {
        background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0);
        color: rgba(0,0,0,0);
        position: fixed;
        display: inline-block;
        white-space: nowrap;
        font-family: Arial;
        left: 0;
        top: 0;
        width: 4px;
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0;
        border: 0;
        padding: 0;
        overflow: hidden;
        z-index: 9000000;
        cursor: default;
        -ms-user-select: none;
        user-select: none;
    }
    #daric-fav-overlay:hover {
        color: #DFDFDF;
        width: auto;
        overflow: auto;
        background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
    }

    .daric-folder:hover, .daric-fav:hover {
        background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.2);
    }

    .daric-folder, .daric-sub-folder {
        cursor: default;
        padding: 4px;
        margin: 0;
        white-space: nowrap;
    }

    .daric-fav {
        cursor: default;
        padding: 4px;
        margin: 0;
    }

    .daric-hidden {
        width: 0;
        height: 0;
        padding: 0;
        margin: 0;
        border: 0;
        top: -400px;
        left: -400px;
        position: fixed;
    }
```

Preview of current results.
Sidebar appearing when hovering on the left side of the web-page:

[image: sidebar appearing when hovering on the left side of the web-page]

Comment: 1) Show us the exact error message and indicate the source line where it occurs. 2) Show manifest.json's `permissions`. 3) Use [search to find existing answers](https://www.google.com/search?q=stackoverflow+chrome+extension+favicons) for favicons problem.

Comment: I have added the manifest.json file contents.

Comment: If this code is running in an extension page then you can use `chrome.tabs.create({url: '.....'})` instead of `window.open`.

Comment: That's interesting to know. But the extension page refuses to have a sidebar loaded as I am doing it. I also want the bookmarks to behave like the real ones and simply load the page in the current tab. Unless someone has another way of creating a sidebar that goes arround creating a new element on a webpage, I'm opened to alternatives. I followed online helps on extension creations and fell on this method for creating sidebars.

Comment: 1) What is this "sidebar" and how do you create it? 2) To open stuff in current tab use `chrome.tabs.update`

Comment: chrome.whatever will not work. This creates a DIV element inside the current loaded page so the script executes as if the webpage had this already integrated inside its HTML content. That's why I'm asking here because I don't know how to make this happen. Do I need to rewrite the whole thing? If so, how do I create a side panel that responds on mousehover if it is not an in-page HTML element? I am trying to unlock some chrome constraints with this sidebar. Everything works fine asside from these 2 last details, load a "file://" url and get the bookmarks' fav icons. That's all there is left.

Comment: In your content script you can create an iframe element that points to a html file inside your extension (see how to use chrome.runtime.getURL). That file should be listed in [web_accessible_resources](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/manifest/web_accessible_resources). That html will be like a normal extension page with your own scripts which can use all of `chrome` API.

Comment: That's an interesting point of view. The iframe. I am just wondering how I can get this file:// load in the current opened tab using this iframe idea because I know there is also some security stuff surrounding elements like that. So the question is really, how would I go about loading this "file://" url in the current tab using this iframe idea or any other possible workarrounds?

Comment: The iframe has a fully privileged extension context so it can use chrome.tabs.update with `file` URLs.

Comment: Could I have a sample of how I would list my favorites inside an ifram when my HTML file is not populated yet with this information? And then, how can I get my populated iframe to send the chrome.tabs.update the url sent in the clickable element that contains the url of my bookmark. I am still scorching google and other places to try and get this to work, but boy, is that so hard. I also fell on the fact that some pages, like chrome store, don't show my side panel

Comment: You would simply move the code that generates the HTML to that iframe's script. An iframe is just like any page so it has its own DOM, document, and so on.

Comment: The iframe requires a URL and I simply dump all the code into innerHTML. Unless we can drop HTML contents directly in an iframe without using an URL. I'll wait to see if someone can confirm that but also do my search in the mean time too.

Comment: No, see my first comment about iframe: it'll point to a file in your extension. Inside that html file you'll load a script and that script will build html and assign it to document.body.innerHTML or whatever just like you do it currently.

Comment: Okay! I see. So what would be the way to load a file from my extension files folder and how would I detect that the loaded file is effectively the ne in the iframe AND detect which tab to load my clicked bookmark. And I still am trying to figure out how to load the cached favicons from chrome inside an img element.

Comment: No need to detect anything because 1) the script will run only inside the iframe, 2) a click event will occur inside the active tab.

Comment: I found iframe.srcdoc which seams to do the job as you are explaining. Now, I am still left with how to retrieve each bookmark's favicon cached by chrome so I can load them in an img tag. Once I have a working code, I'll post the solution, I just have a few checks to do first.

Comment: No, srcdoc will run the code in the same origin as the page, it won't be the extension cntext which is needed to use chrome.tabs.update and other chrome API. Anyway, I won't follow this thread anymore as I already explained it like 10 times.

Comment: I'm sorry if I don't get how to load a bookmarks list from a variable in background.js into an HTML file that will be loaded into another pseudo window "iframe". I'm trying to figure out how the information will transfer. I've seen many people questiong here on stack overflow and many of them have people submit a code sample to help them. I'm trying my best to follow simple comments with no code samples. AND again, I still have noone that answered my question about the favicons.

Comment: Pressed enter too fast, I wanted to add a Thank you for helping me out as much as you can. It's still very appreciated :)

Comment: See [Pass data or modify extension html in a new tab/window](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54715122)

Comment: I have updated my files, added a content.js script. But for some reason, the DIV element is not always created and sometimes, emptied. And again, I still have no clue on how to extract the fav icons chrome stores in it's cache.