# Chrome Extension: Access tabs from popup window

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I am developing an extension for Chrome browser that spawns a detached popup in it's own popup window. I need to be able to access the browser tabs just as I would from the "attached" popup. I have tried several approaches and I must just be missing something fundamental. Any help or guidance in the right direction would be greatly appreciated.

Here is the code I am using to reference tabs inside the attached popup and it works fine:

```
chrome.tabs.query({active: true, lastFocusedWindow: true}, tabs => {
        let url = tabs[0].url;
        //alert(url);
            if(url.includes("https://admin.webcasts.com/admin/summary"))
            {
                scrapeMeetingData()
            }
            else
            {
            alert("Please load a meeting summary in Global Meet and try again.")
            }
            });
        
        }, false);
```

When I try to use this in the "detached" popup however, it fails. I am guessing it tries to return the tabs of the "detached" popup window at this point (which there are none).

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It runs in its own window so lastFocusedWindow refers to the popup. You can save the original window id before opening the popup in a variable and use it then in query(). Depending on the event you're using there are several methods, one of them is chrome.windows.getLastFocused, see also [Pass data or modify extension html in a new tab/window](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54715122)

Comment: @wOxxOm perfect. That gave me what I needed to figure things out. Thanks.