# Chrome Extension Content Script Match Pattern for a Local URL/File?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, content-script

I have a Chrome Extension that when I click on a button on the Popup page, it sends a msg to a Background script. This Background script then creates a Tab and the URL is just the index.html file that goes along in the extension installation. (it's in the root of the extension's folder)

```
chrome.tabs.create({ url: "index.html" }, (tab) => { });
```

Well, it does create the tab with the correct index.html, but the url in the address bar / omnibox is:

```
chrome-extension://pdkkaldkelomkfiohdhcklphjclggmoh/index.html
```

And the problem is that I need to attach a Content Script for this index.html and in the Official Chrome Docs at `https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv3/match_patterns/`
there's no matches for something like: `chrome-extension://`

I tried using:  and file:///* , no error msgs, but when I'm at the index.html page, in the Dev Tools I check for the Content Scripts tab, but the content.js was not loaded.

Also tested with:

```
"content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": [
        "*://pdkkaldkelomkfiohdhcklphjclggmoh/index.html"
      ],
      "js": [
        "content.js"
      ]
    }
  ]
```

no error msgs, and with the full path: "chrome-extension://pdkkaldkelomkfiohdhcklphjclggmoh/index.html" I get an error when refreshing the extension:

```
Invalid value for 'content_scripts[0].matches[0]': Invalid scheme.
Could not load manifest.
```

It doesn't accept the "chrome-extension://" part of the match string.

I'm probably doing something wrong because I'm sure I can work with a local file that will be installed as part of the extension's set of files.

Any ideas please let me know and thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

Content scripts are designed to be added to foreign pages that don't belong to your own extension whereas `index.html` belongs to your extension, the technical meaning is that the URL starts with `chrome-extension://yourExtensionID/` in Chrome or `moz-extension://yourExtensionID/` in FF.

**So simply load the script in your index.html:**

```html
<script src="index.js"></script>
```

Note that by default extension pages disallow inline JS (scripts without `src` or attributes like `onclick`), see [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13591983/onclick-or-inline-script-isnt-working-in-extension) for more info in case you want to use inline JS anyway.

Comment: I already have the index.js loaded in the same way as you mentioned above, but I guess the important part of your comment is that you say: "Content scripts are designed to be added to foreign pages that don't belong to your own extension..." which I realize now is the key ... I mean, I'm thinking in a wrong way, instead of trying to attach a content script into my index.html, I'll need a way to make the background script (in manifest v3, bg script is a service worker) send a msg to index.js?

Comment: See [Pass data or modify extension html in a new tab/window](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54715122)

Comment: Thanks, I'll definitely check that out :-)