# Chrome Extension Popup get URL of tab from previous popup

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, url, google-chrome-extension

I have a chrome extension that opens up a small panel which contains a few buttons that open other popups. The new popups need the url of the tab the original extension was run on but I cannot seem to get the URL correctly. I am a complete noob at chrome extensions so I apologise

Below code is from when you click on the icon **popup.html**

```
<div class="buttondiv">
      <button
        id="btnOpen"
        class="btn btn-secondary"
        style="text-align: center; font-family: Montserrat"
      >
        Run Web Extension
      </button>
```

**popup.js**

```
$(function () {
  $("#btnOpen").click(function () {
    chrome.windows.create({
      url: chrome.runtime.getURL("newpopup.html"),
      type: "panel", height: 710, width: 1012,
       
  });
 
});
```

This opens the newpopup.html. The associated js file needs the url of the original tab the extension was opened on.

I've tried:

```
chrome.tabs.query({
    active: true,
    lastFocusedWindow: true
}, function(tabs) {
    var tabURL = tabs[0].url;
    console.log(tabs);
    alert(tabURL);
});
```

But this only returns the current url of the new popup. Even if i were to get the lastFocusedWindow thing to work wouldn't it return the url of the original popup? Any and all help will be appreciated

Comment: Get the URL in the original popup first and then transfer it to the new popup as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54715122).

Comment: Thank you so much! The first approach (localstorage) worked like a charm. I had been trying to use sendMessage to no avail.