# How to pass a message from content script to a modal iframe in chrome extension?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, web, google-chrome-extension

I have created a background script to create context menu and select text. And I've successfully get the selected text from background script to content script. And I've managed to open a modal on context menu click.
Now I have a trouble passing that selected text to this modal. How to do that?
I am using react to render this modal.

I use this code to send data to modal when the context menu button is clicked:

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(
        function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
            console.log(sender.tab ?
                        "from a content script:" + sender.tab.url :
                        "from the extension");
            if (request.type === "send the word")
            sendResponse({word: info.selectionText});
        }
        );
```

This is how I inititate the modal:

```
iframe.src = chrome.extension.getURL("popup.html");
```

And I receive the selected text inside modal as follows:

```
chrome.runtime.sendMessage({type: "send the word"}, function(response) {
        setWord(response.word);
    });
```

Comment: See [Pass data or modify extension html in a new tab/window](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54715122)

Comment: I need a fast and reliable solution. Because the user want to quickly select a text and i want to display it in the modal. So what is the effective way to communicate selected text to the modal?

Comment: @wOxxOm can't i just send message from content script to the modal on that page?

Comment: Show us the code that opens the modal and describe it in detail so we understand which file or context it is.

Comment: @wOxxOm I manage to get the text in the modal by sending a message and returning a response from background script. But it is always showing the first selected value. Why isn't changing as I change the selection?

Comment: It's impossible to help unless you add [MCVE](/help/mcve).

Comment: @wOxxOm I added the code, check it out.

Comment: The code looks fine so the problem is elsewhere, maybe in setWord. Use devtools to set breakpoints inside the listeners and debug the code when the message is sent.

Comment: No, I don't think it is problem in setWord. I console logged `response.word` it  is always printing the same value. May be ```sendResponse()``` is called once?

Comment: @wOxxOm How about using long-lived connection?

Comment: Then the mistake is in the code that sets `info` in the background script. If your onMessage listener is inside onClicked, you need to unregister it after sendResponse by making the listener a named function and using chrome.runtime.onMessage.removeListener after sendResponse.