# Chrome extension React interact with background pages (V3)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-chrome-extension

Trying to create my Chrome extension and faced with problem how to paste content in background pages opened from popup. My architecture is now like that:

Manifest:

```
{
  "name": "extension",
  "description": "description",
  "version": "1.0",
  "manifest_version": 3,
  "action": {
    "default_popup": "index.html",
    "default_title": "Open extension"
  },
  "icons": {
    "16": "logo192.png",
    "48": "logo192.png",
    "128": "logo192.png"
  },
  "permissions": ["storage", "activeTab", "tabs"]
}
```

index.tsx

```
ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById('root')
)
```

App.tsx

```
const { ROUTE_START, ROUTE_LOGIN, ROUTE_BACKGROUND } = appRoutes

export default function AppRouter(): JSX.Element {
  return (
    <MemoryRouter>
      <Routes>
        <Route element={<WelcomeExt />} path={ROUTE_START} />
        <Route element={<LoginExtensionPage />} path={ROUTE_LOGIN} />
        <Route element={<LoginExtensionPage />} path={ROUTE_BACKGROUND} />
      </Routes>
    </MemoryRouter>
  )
}
```

Welcome.tsx

```
export default function WelcomeExt(): JSX.Element {
  const handleClick = () => {
    chrome.tabs.create({
      url: 'background.html',
    })
  }
  return (
    <ExtensionHOC alignItems="center">
      <img src={logo} alt="logo" style={{ width: '60px', marginTop: '104px' }} />
      <Typography
        variant="h1"
        style={{
          margin: '32px 0 8px',
          fontSize: '32px',
          fontWeight: '700',
          letterSpacing: '-0.5px',
          lineHeight: '38px',
        }}
      >
        Title
      </Typography>
      <Typography
        variant="subtitle1"
        style={{
          color: '#04121D',
          letterSpacing: '-0.25px',
        }}
      >
        text secondary
      </Typography>
      <Button variant="contained" sx={{ marginTop: '28px', minWidth: '137px' }} onClick={handleClick}>
        Get started
      </Button>
    </ExtensionHOC>
  )
}
```

Trying to find docs about this issue but nothing I have found answers me on this question. Need information about managing other than index.html pages or I need to specify another routing architecture, script execution etc.

Comment: If you mean passing data and modifying the page, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54708537).

Comment: I mean, page than opens in chrome-extension://EXTENSION-ID/background.html

might have markups and logic such as common react route page

Comment: It's simply a different page so it has its own scripts.

Comment: I understand this. But can't understand what shall I pass to background.js to render JSX elements inside it. Or this isn't work in this way and I need to create markups and JS logic inside it?

Comment: You'll create another app there. To pass the data see the answer I've linked.