# How to solve Messaging Error occuring from Background Script to another script?

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome-extension, frontend, messaging

I am trying to send some selected text from the current page to an HTML page. Since, I can not do it directly, I am using message passing: content script to background script, then background script to the HTML page. But get error if the HTML is not open already, even then I get an error first time:

> background.js:1 Uncaught (in promise) Error: Could not establish
> connection. Receiving end does not exist.

If I close the page, then run again, this error will keep happening.

What is the solution ?

My code is given below:

#### popup.js

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function (request, sender, sendResponse) {
console.log("from popup = \n"+request.bg);
})
```

#### background.js

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function (request, sender, sendResponse) {

chrome.tabs.create({url: 'popup.html'});
chrome.runtime.sendMessage({bg: request.exc})
                                                                              })
```

#### content.js

```
string=[];
function doc_keyUp(e) {
if (getSelectionText() != "")  {
if (e.key === '1') {
    string=getSelectionText();
    chrome.runtime.sendMessage({exc: string});
            
                   } 
                                }
                      } // doc_keyUp(e)
console.log('The program has started!!!');  
// register the handler 
document.addEventListener('keyup', doc_keyUp, false);                              

function getSelectionText() {
    var text = "";
     text = window.getSelection().toString();
    if (window.getSelection) {
        text = window.getSelection().toString();
    } 
    else if (document.selection && document.selection.type != "Control") {
        text = document.selection.createRange().text;
    }
    return text;    
}
```

#### popup.html

```
<html>
<script src="popup.js">
</script>
</html>
```

I am doing this to buid a chrome extension, so if required then:

#### manifest.json

```
{
  "name": "",
  "version": "1.0",
  "description":"",
  "manifest_version": 3,
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
      "js": ["content.js"]
    }
  ],
  "action": {
    "default_title": "T"
  },
  "background":{
    "service_worker": "background.js"
  },
  "permissions": ["tabs","storage"]
}
```

Post Script:

1. Is there an alternative way to send data directly from content script to script of an HTML (e.g. here popup.js is such script) without going through background script?
2. Is there a to get a variable from background script without message passing to any other script? I saw solutions using `chrome.extension.getBackgroundPage()` but it does not work anymore after manifest v3. Is there anything else?

Comment: See [Pass data or modify extension html in a new tab/window](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54708537)

Comment: @wOxxOm Hi!, I could solve the problem the alternative way does not work (using storage), can you tell me why I get the error and how to solve it? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use localStorage to send and get items. If your item not included in your localStorage you can initialize it.

content.js

```
localStorage.setItem("bg", "#000000"); // <- You can send json or whatever you want
```

popup.js

```
var bg = localStorage.getItem("bg");
```

or you can use [chrome.storage](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/storage/) API

content.js

```
chrome.storage.local.set({bg: value}, function() {
  console.log('Value is set to ' + value);
});
```

popup.js

```
chrome.storage.local.get(['bg'], function(result) {
  console.log('Key is ' + result.bg);
});
```

Add `storage` to permissions.

And you need to add to your extension permissions (manifest file
)
But you should be careful because

> **confidential user information should not be stored! The storage area isn't encrypted.**

Working Code:

content.js

```
string=[];
function doc_keyUp(e) {
    if (getSelectionText() != "")  {
        if (e.key === 'Enter') { 
            string=getSelectionText();
            chrome.storage.local.set({bg: string}, function() {
                console.log('Bg is set to ' + value);
            });
            chrome.runtime.sendMessage({});
        } 
    }
} // doc_keyUp(e)
console.log('The program has started!!!');  
    // register the handler 
document.addEventListener('keyup', doc_keyUp, false);                              
    
function getSelectionText() {
    var text = "";
    text = window.getSelection().toString();
    if (window.getSelection) {
        text = window.getSelection().toString();
    } 
    else if (document.selection && document.selection.type != "Control") {
        text = document.selection.createRange().text;
    }
    return text;    
}
```

popup.js

```
chrome.storage.local.get(['bg'], function(result) {
    alert('Bg is ' + result.bg);
});
```

background.js

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function (request, sender, sendResponse) {
    chrome.tabs.create({url: 'popup.html'});
});
```

I changed `e.key === 'Enter'` in `content.js` for better testing. And I deleted `chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener` from `popup.js` because you will call popup after `background.js` receive message so you don't need to get message everytime in `popup.js`.You need to get value once when popup created.

Selected Text Image:

[image]

And popup alert:

[image]

Comment: You can't see your chrome.storage.local values on chrome own application but you can use this chrome extension 'https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/storage-area-explorer/ocfjjjjhkpapocigimmppepjgfdecjkb'. It will add 'Storage Explorer' Tab your console and you can see from there