# Send message from background.js to popup

Tags: javascript, vue.js, google-chrome-extension, chrome-extension-manifest-v3

I want to implement FCM in my chrome extension.
At the mement after a lot of research I've found that the quick and best way to implement fcm is using the old API `chrome.gcm`. At the moment this solution seems working fine and when the extension is loaded I'm able to get an fcm token.

Now what I want to do is to pass the token to the popup that is powered by vue.js I'm trying with this code but without success.

background.js

```js
const openPopup = () => {
    chrome.windows.create({
        type: 'popup',
        height: 520,
        width: 440,
        url: chrome.runtime.getURL('popup.html')
    })
}

const registeredToken = (registrationId) => {
    console.log('FCM Token')
    console.log(registrationId)
    openPopup()
    chrome.runtime.sendMessage({fcmToken: registrationId})
    if( chrome.runtime.lastError ) {
        console.log('error')
    }
}

const notificationId = (id) => {
    if(chrome.runtime.lastError) {
        console.log(chrome.runtime.lastError)
    }
    console.log(id)
}

chrome.runtime.onInstalled.addListener( () => {
    console.log('FCM extension installed')
})

chrome.action.onClicked.addListener( (tab) => {
    console.log(tab)
    openPopup()
})

chrome.gcm.register(['my_sender_id'], registeredToken)

chrome.gcm.onMessage.addListener( (message) => {
    console.log(message, message.data["gcm.notification.title"])
    chrome.notifications.create('', {
        type: 'basic',
        iconUrl: 'letter.png',
        title: message.data["gcm.notification.title"],
        message: message.data["gcm.notification.body"],
        buttons: [
            { title: 'Dismiss' },
            { title: 'Reply' }
        ]
    }, notificationId)
})

chrome.notifications.onButtonClicked.addListener( (notificationId, buttonIndex) => {
    console.log('button clicked')
    console.log(notificationId, buttonIndex)
})
```

popup.vue file

```js
<template>
    <div class="main_app">
        <h1>Hello {{msg}}</h1>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    name: 'popupView',
    data () {
        return {
            msg: ''
        }
    },
    mounted() {
        chrome.runtime.onMessage( (message, sender, sendResponse) => {
            console.log(message, sender, sendResponse)
            this.msg = message
        })
    },
    methods: {

    }
}

</script>
```

What I've noticed is that the `chrome.runtime.sendMessage({fcmToken: registrationId})` will not work and on the popup side I'm unable to send or get messages from background

How I can pass messages between the vue.js powered popup and the background.js file of the extension?

Is better to use firebase client library to get push messages or the gcm is fine for this scope?

Comment: The popup isn't ready to receive, you need to wait or pass the data via URL/storage, see [examples](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54708537).

Comment: So basically I need to wait to send the message to the popup until it is opened right?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `chrome.tabs.query` and `chrome.tabs.sendMessage` [APIs](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv3/messaging/#simple) to send a message from the background to the Popup.

```
   chrome.tabs.query({}, function (tabs) {
    tabs.forEach((tab) => {
      chrome.tabs.sendMessage( 
        tab.id,
        youtPayload, 
        function (response) {
         // do something here if you want
        }
      );
    });
  });
```

That's it!

Comment: Here: https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv3/messaging/#simple is the documentation

Answer (score 1):

I spend lots of hours to finding solution to the same proble and still not find any.

My current understanding is, that we are trying to do and use method for the purpose, they wasnt ment to be used for.

Key information leading to this:

- popup.js can share the same. Js file and objects with background.js
- documentation primarely is talking about passing data between web page (content.js) and others (popup.js or background.js)

Comment: You should attach code snippet what you have done yourself without code no one will be able to help and tell you what is possibly wrong with your code

Comment: I thought, that code isnt needed as I understand the problem lies elsewhere. I can provide my code, but it is basically same code and same errors as newbiedev shared.

the problem is, that sent postMessage from popup.js to background.js works. But the opposite direction always ends with error in both cases: 1/ use postMessage method in openport, 2/ tabs.sendMessage with tabId. Both report error, addlistener is never launched and error says, that there is no receiver. 
I am now working on solution to open port from content.js file, which should work as expected.