# Enable zoom of about:blank page in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, zooming

I am writing a Chrome extension which generates an extra tab (using `window.open()`), containing som extracted data from the original web page where the extension is running. This tab has the "adress" `about:blank`. In contrast to other tabs, Chrome does not provide support for zooming in and out of this (or any other) blank tab. Can zooming be enabled here? I have found some references to zooming in other posts, but not in the context of `about:blank`.

Comment: What have you tried? What didn't work for you? Can you please show some code?

Comment: @RahulSharma I'm sorry, I haven't tried anything except applying the menu commands Zoom In and Zoom Out, which did nothing. I don't know what else to try, or what code could be applied to remedy this so I have no code to show.

Comment: For zoom do you mean browser zoom?
If so, you could think to open your window whith **chrome.windows.create** and then zoom a tab of that window with **chrome.tab.setZoom**.


    

But Have I understand well? Zooming the void?

Comment: I guess you'll have to use an extension tab: send a message from the content script to the background script with the data, the background script will open `show.html` page from your extension and [pass the data there](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54715122).

Comment: @Robbi: the tab is not void, since the extension has put content into it. But, per your and @wOxxOm's suggestions, I have gone for `chrome.tabs.create()` instead of `window.open()`. See my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have now tried to follow method 4 of @wOxxOm's instructions in the [linked page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54708537/pass-data-or-modify-extension-html-in-a-new-tab-window/54715122#54715122), using `chrome.tabs.create()` and `chrome.tabs.setZoomSettings()`. The demo below manages to create a tab and place a Zoom in/out icon in the Chrome toolbar when the user clicks on the Google logo on a Google page. When I set `mode: "automatic"`in the `setZoomSettings()`'s `zoomSettings` object in `background.js`, the zoom buttons appeared in the Chrome toolbar and actually zoomed, although I had to choose the menu command `View -> Zoom In (or Out)` before the zoom buttons actually showed up. Please feel free to point out bugs or unelegant solutions below.

**Note**: this does not strictly answer the question asked, since the generated tab will not be an `about:blank` tab. However, it provides a solution to the underlying problem.

**manifest.json**

```
{
  "manifest_version": 3,
  "name": "zoom demo",
  "version": "0.1",
  "description": "zoom demo",
  "background": {
    "service_worker": "background.js"
  },
  "permissions":["tabs"],   
 "content_scripts": [{
      "js": ["jquery.js","content.js"],
     "matches": ["https://www.google.com/*"]
  }],
  "web_accessible_resources":[{"resources":[], "matches": ["https://www.google.com/*"]}]
}
```

**content.js:**

```
jQuery(function($){
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $(document).on("click", "img[alt='Google']", function () {
        chrome.runtime.sendMessage({command:"createTab"});
    });
  });
});
```

**new_tab.html:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8"/>
</head>
<body>
    <h2>This is an h2 heading – does it zoom?</h2>
    <script src="new_tab.js"></script>
</body>
```

**new_tab.js:**

```
chrome.runtime.sendMessage({command:"setTabZoom"});
```

**background.js:**

```
var replyObject = {};
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(
  function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
    switch(request.command){
      case "createTab":
        chrome.tabs.create({url:"new_tab.html"});
      break;
      case "setTabZoom":
       chrome.tabs.query({ active: true, currentWindow: true, highlighted: true }, function (tabs) {
        let currTabId = tabs[0].id;
        chrome.tabs.setZoomSettings(currTabId, {
          defaultZoomFactor: 1,
          mode: "automatic",
          scope: "per-tab"},
        );
      });
      break;
    };
    return true;
});
```