# browser.extension.getViews() from extensioin backround script does not return the tabs in incognito mode in firefox

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, firefox-addon

I am using the tabs.create API to create a new tab and then using tabs.getViews() on tabs.onUpdated listener to get the newly created tab. I am doing this because I need to run something after the page has loaded completely(status === "complete" in getViews()). But when using extension in firefox's inPrivate(incognito) tab the new tab created is in incognito and getViews does not return the tab. Is there any way to get the incognito tabs in tabs.getViews() or open the new tab (using tabs.create) in non-incognito from incognito window in firefox?

PS: Chrome opens the new tab in non-incognito mode even when using extension from incognito window.

```
browser.tabs.create({
        url: viewTabUrl
    }, function(tab) {
        var targetId = tab.id;
        updateEditorInterval = setInterval(function(){
            browser.tabs.get(targetId, function(tab){
                if(tab.status === "complete" && !isEditorUpdated) {
                    clearInterval(updateEditorInterval);
                    var view = browser.extension.getViews({tabId: targetId});  //No I18N
                    view.myFunction();
                }
            });
        },200);
});
```

Comment: There's a simpler method: add a parameter to viewTabUrl so that the tab's script will call myFunction itself. See example 2 in [Pass data or modify extension html in a new tab/window](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54715122)

Comment: But I have an image blob that should be given to the tab created. I have a method that receives the image so I find the view and then call that specific function in that view like view.myFunction(imageData).

Comment: Incognito is running in a different process, AFAIK, so you can't access the view directly. You can use URL.createObjectURL to pass the blob.