# Can't create a chrome window and update its html from a background script

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome-extension, frontend, content-script

**Problem**

I'm building a chrome extension that injects some buttons into a webpage and, when clicked, allows a user to send some files to my backend server. After it sends those files, I get a response back from the server.

I want to display that response in a separate window, but when I create the window, it doesn't change the display text and uses the default text I put in the p tag.

Additionally, I get this error from my service worker when trying to send the window a message from my background.js that contains the data I want to be displayed.

***"Unchecked runtime.lastError: Could not establish connection. Receiving end does not exist."***

**Background**

The communication line I have setup is as follows.

I have a content script that calls my injection script to inject buttons into the web page.

When the buttons send a message to the server and the response is received, I send that information back to the content script via window.postMessage().

My content script has a listener, sending the message to the background script.

The background script has an onMessage listener that creates a new chrome tab and window. The chrome tab itself uses the chrome.runtime.getURL to create the HTML page. The HTML page is linked to a script called notification.js. Notification js has a listener that should receive messages sent from the background.js which will modify what is displayed.

Currently, though the page only pops up and its text isn't modified.

Is there another method I can use to update my newly created window? Or is this the incorrect way to be sending messages for chrome extensions.

**Code**

**Content Script**

```
function injectScript(file_path, tag){
    let node = document.body;
    let script = document.createElement("script");
    script.setAttribute('type', 'text/javascript');
    script.setAttribute('src', file_path);
    console.log(script);

    node.appendChild(script);
}

let script_url = chrome.runtime.getURL("scripts/inject_script.js");
injectScript(script_url, 'body');


try {
    window.addEventListener("message", function(event) {

        if (event.data.type
            && (event.data.type == "FROM_PAGE")) {

            console.log("sending message to bg")
            chrome.runtime.sendMessage({output: event.data = "waiting"}, (response) => {
                console.log(response);
            });
        }

    }, false);
}catch (e) {
    console.log(e);
}
```

**Inject Script**

```
        fileInput.addEventListener("change", function (){
            const formData = new FormData();
            formData.append("files", fileInput.files[0]);
            formData.append("courseId", courseId);
            formData.append("assignmentId", assignmentId);
            formData.append("userType", "STUDENT")


            fetch(endpoint, {
                method: "POST",
                headers: new Headers({
                    'Authorization': bearerToken
                }),
                body: formData
            }).catch(console.error).then( async response =>  {
                let fileSubmit_response = await response.json();

                console.log(fileSubmit_response);
                alert(fileSubmit_response.output);

                let output = fileSubmit_response.output;

                console.log("sending message to content")
                window.postMessage( {type: "FROM_PAGE", output});

            });
        });
```

**Background Script**

```
try {

    chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function (message, sender, sendResponse) {
        console.log(message.output);
        console.log(sender);

        sendResponse("msg recieved");

        if (message.output === 'waiting') {
            chrome.tabs.create({url: chrome.runtime.getURL('components/compilation_notification.html'), active: false}, function(tab)
            {
                // After the tab has been created, open a window to inject the tab
                chrome.windows.create({
                    tabId: tab.id,
                    type: 'popup',
                    focused: true
                    // incognito, top, left, ...
                })

                console.log("before message is sent")
                
                //should send data to newly created tab
                chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tab.id, {output: message.output, type: "compilation_results"}, (response) => {
                    console.log(response);
                });

            });
        }
    })
}

catch (e) {
    console.log(e)
}
```

**Notification.js**

```
//script that is being used in compilation_notification.html
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function (msg, sender, sendResponse) {

    if (msg.type === 'compilation_results') {

        sendResponse("confirmed");

        document.getElementById('update-text').value = msg.output;
    }
});
```

Comment: Please see this. [Sending an asynchronous response using sendResponse](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/runtime/onMessage#sending_an_asynchronous_response_using_sendresponse)

Comment: The new page isn't ready yet to receive your sendMessage. Either wait for it or use storage, see [these examples](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54715122).

Comment: Thank you for the comments I will check out both solutions!

Comment: I followed wOxxOm example number 4 "MV2/MV3: Background script relay messaging in two hops," and I'm able to update my new page now.