# How do I create a new window and send data to it from context worker (chrome extension)

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I'm working on a chrome extension and need to create a new window from a context worker. This new window is a local HTML file and so the new window opens up with a "chrome-extension" <scheme>. I want to do some processing and then send data **from the context worker** to the new window created.

Context worker code:

```
 const window = await chrome.windows.create({
  url: "../summary/summary.html",
});

//some processing

chrome.runtime.sendMessage(
    window.tabs[0].id, //should be extensionID (not sure how to get it)
    {
      action: "setData",
      data: some data
    },
    null
  )
  .then(() => {
    console.log("worked");
  })
  .catch((e) => console.error(e));
```

Once the new window receives the data, in its JS file, I would like it to modify the DOM of the new window.

summary.html:

```
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="summary.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="dummy">Dummy</div>
  </body>
  <script src="summary.js"></script>
</html>
```

summary.js:

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener((msg, sender) => {
  console.log("summary js ran");
  if (msg.action === "setData") {
    console.log(msg.data);
    document.getElementById("content").innerHTML = msg.data;
  }
});
```

I am unsure if I should treat summary.js as a content file, or if there is something else I do not understand.

Any advice would be much appreciated!

Comment: Its implementation is probably possible.
However, the argument of `chrome.runtime.sendMessage` is not the tab ID.

Comment: Reverse the direction: use chrome.runtime.sendMessage in summary.js and onMessage 
+ sendResponse in SW. See also [Pass data or modify extension html in a new tab/window](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54715122)

Comment: @wOxxOm that was perfect! I changed some logic around and made it work using your advice! Thanks a lot! You're better than ChatGPT!

Answer (score 0):

Based on the advice of @wOxxOm, I switched the logic around and it works!

summary.js:

```
chrome.runtime.sendMessage(
  {
    action: "setData",
  },
  (res) => {
    console.log(res);
    //can use the response data here
  }
);
```

context worker:

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener((msg, sender, sendResponse) => {
  if (msg.action === "setData") {
    generateResponse().then(sendResponse);
    return true; //needed this line as generateResponse is an async function
  }
});
```