# Opening a new chrome window and executing a script from a chrome extension

Tags: chrome-extension-manifest-v3

I need to open a new window and run some javascript in it from a service worker of a manifest v3 extension. However, I need to pass arguments to the code.

This is the solution I've come up with:

```js
const window = await chrome.windows.create({ url: "about:blank" })

chrome.scripting.executeScript({
    target: { tabId: window.tabs[0].id },
    args: ["Hello, World!"],
    func: (text) => {
        console.log(text)
    }
})
```

Problem is, it appears that the extension can't have the correct permissions in `about:blank`.

Comment: See [Pass data or modify extension html in a new tab/window](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54715122)