# Chrome extension sendMessage "could not establish connection" error with Vite

Tags: reactjs, typescript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, vite

I am building a Chrome extension that launches a new tab and sends a message to the tab with data.

When I build a production version of the app with rollup, there is a static index.html file and the extension works fine.

In dev mode, Vite isn't producing a static HTML file and so when the extension is served in the new tab, I think there is a race of some kind and the message isn't succeeding unless I put it inside a micro setTimeout.

Any ideas how I can have the extension run fine in dev mode? I am working around it for now by building the extension as production in watch mode on every change but it defeats the purpose of Vite a little bit from what I understand.

The exact error is `Uncaught (in promise) Error: Could not establish connection. Receiving end does not exist.`

```
export function launchSvgGobbler() {
  chrome.action.onClicked.addListener(async ({ url }) => {
    try {
      // Create a new tab and send the data to the content script
      const tab = await utils.createNewTab()
      const sendMessage = () => chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tab.id!, { data: 'data' })

      // Vite HMR issue. The page is loaded not statically, so we need to wait
      // Production build works fine because static HTML is loaded.
      if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development') {
        setTimeout(sendMessage, 50)
      } else {
        sendMessage()
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.log('Error launching', error)
    }
  })
}
```

This is the createTab function. It works fine but it's here for reference:

```
/**
 * Awaits the loading of a newly created tab and return the tab config.
 * @param url The url to open relative to the extension. Defaults to index.html.
 */
export function createNewTab(url = 'index.html'): Promise<chrome.tabs.Tab> {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    chrome.tabs.create({ url, active: true }, (tab) => {
      const listener = (updatedTabId, changeInfo, updatedTab) => {
        if (
          tab.id &&
          updatedTabId === tab.id &&
          changeInfo.status === 'complete' &&
          updatedTab.status === 'complete'
        ) {
          chrome.tabs.onUpdated.removeListener(listener)
          resolve(updatedTab)
        }
      }

      chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(listener)
    })
  })
}
``
```

Comment: You can reverse the direction of communication so you won't need onUpdated listener. The new page will use chrome.runtime.sendMessage, while launchSvgGobbler will temporarily add onMessage listener, which will check `sender.tab?.id`, respond with data, and unregister. See also [Pass data or modify extension html in a new tab/window](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54715122)

Comment: @wOxxOm! I see you all over these Chrome extension support threads I'm reading on the internet. Thanks for taking the time to help me out. I'm going to try this approach.